# Filtering/erasing duplicate entries using fluid

Tags: duplicates, typo3, fluid

i'm trying to find a way to erase duplicate entries using fluid. The idea was to use f:alias and then counting the items with the same title.

But my results are ridiculous. The counting is totally wrong. 
Is it possible overall to do something like that in fluid?

I tried like this:

```
    <f:alias map="{client: '{newsItem->f:count()}'}">
        <f:if condition="{client -> f:count()}==1">
            <f:then>
                <f:if condition="{newsItem.teaser}">        

                    <f:then>
                        <span itemprop="description">{newsItem.teaser -> f:format.crop(maxCharacters: '{settings.cropMaxCharacters}', respectWordBoundaries:'1') -> f:format.html()}</span>
                    </f:then>
                    <f:else> 
                        <p>There are {newsItem} records in database</p>
                        <li>{newsItem.txPblcexpandnewsClient}</li>      
                    </f:else> 
                </f:if> 
            </f:then> 
            <f:else> 
                else 1       
            </f:else>  
        </f:if>         
    </f:alias>
```

Beste regards

blue

Answer (score 2):

Fluid should not to use to heavy for logical context. If it to complex it belongs in the controller.

But try to use the group ViewHelper grouped by title.

Answer (score 0):

as Rene already said: avoid this kind of logic in fluid!

but if you really can not do it in another way one solution could be:
use ext:vhs to define and change variables on the fly in fluid.
So you can do 'Gruppenverarbeitung' (I don't know a translation of this german term):

```html
<v:variable.set name="lastitem" value="" />
<f:for each="items" as="item" iteration="iterator">
  <f:if condition="{lastitem}">
    <f:then>
      <f:if condition="{lastitem.title} == {item.title}">
        <f:then>
          <f:comment>just one item more</f:comment>
          <v:variable.set name="counter">
            <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.calc">{counter}+1</f:cObject>
          </v:variable.set>
        </f:then>
        <f:else>
          <f:comment>output last item</f:comment>
          <f:render partial="showItem" arguments="{item:lastitem, counter:counter}" />
          <f:comment>store new item, reset counter</f:comment>
          <v:variable.set name="lastitem" value="{item}" />
          <v:variable.set name="counter" value="1" />
        </f:else>
      </f:if>
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
      <f:comment>init variables</f:comment>
      <v:variable.set name="lastitem" value="{item}" />
      <v:variable.set name="counter" value="1" />
    </f:else>
  </f:if>
</f:for>
<f:if condition="{lastitem}">
  <f:comment>output last item, if any</f:comment>
  <f:render partial="showItem" arguments="{item:lastitem, counter:counter}" />
</f:if>
```